# Codeigniter get ajax response and pass that data from controller to view

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a problem with my Codeigniter app. I want load some data by ajax. In my page I write onclick function to run jQuery function. And in my function I just Post that response to my controller.Here is my jQuery function

```
 function callplayer(filepath,videocode,createdby){

        $.ajax({
            type    :   "POST",
            url :       base_url+"home/loadVideo",
            data    :   {id:videocode,video:filepath,user_id:createdby},
            success :   function(html){
                    var container = $('#company'); //jquery selector (get element by id)
                       if(html){
                          container.html(html);
                       }

            }
        });

     }
```

And here is my loadVideo function ( My controller )

```
function loadVideo(){
        $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
        # Get Company 
        $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
        $company = $this->load->model('usermanager_model', 'usermanager');
        $company_details[datas] = $this->usermanager->getCompany($user_id); 

        # Pass data to view
        $this->load->view('home_view', $company_details);

}
```

And dont worry about my Model its working fine. 
Here is my view

```
   <div class="video-part">
    <div class="video-details">

        <div id="test">
        <div id="mediaplayer">JW Player goes here</div>
    <?php  echo $url = vimeourl2videourl('http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=2539741') ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url()?>player1/jwplayer.js"></script>
    <div id="mediaplayer">JW Player goes here</div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
            flashplayer: "<?php echo base_url() ?>player1/player.swf",
                        height:"350",
                        width:"500",
            'playlist': [{
            'file': 'www.youtube.com/watch?v=dHBJ8jk3944', 
            'image': '/thumbs/video1.jpg',
            'title': 'The first video'
        },],
        repeat: 'list'           
        });
    </script>
    </div>
        <div class="video-text">

            <div id="company">

            <?php 
            /*
            echo "<pre>";
             print_r($datas);
             echo "</pre>";
                */        
            foreach ($datas as $row) :
           echo $row['companyName']; 
           endforeach;

            ?>

            </div>
            <span class="txt-small">2013-06-09  |  +011 888 88   |   Canada </span>
            <span class="txt-small">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </span>
            <div class="social-icons row-fix">
                <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>images/icon-down.png" alt=""></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>images/icon-here.png" alt=""></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>images/icon-wifi.png" alt=""></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>images/icon-save.png" alt=""></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>images/icon-facebook.png" alt=""></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>images/icon-twitter.png" alt=""></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>images/icon-google.png" alt=""></a>
                <div class="sign-up row-fix">
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url().'registration';?>">Signup</a> <span>|</span> <a href="<?php echo base_url().'registration';?>">Login</a>
                    <div> <a href="#" class="request">Request for Product Info</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is whenever I click image(On-click function) It will load my content with repeated html div tags. But If I print that data in my controller its working fine. Its correctly displayed fetched data only. If I pass that data to view and print then it will show the fetched data with some repeated div tags. My friend told me to use jQuery append function. But I am not familiar with jQuery. Please help to find out proper solution..?

Comment: What is the code in your `home_view` file? It should only echo out the company details and nothing else.

Comment: how does this line of code not throw a notice for you: `$company_details[datas]` ... you're missing quotes there

Comment: PHP will throw a notice and assume 'datas', so it works and OP might not even see the notice depending on his error reporting. It can end up ugly quick if it is also a constant so one should always use quotes.

Comment: @WebNovice I have included my view page.. Please checkout..

Comment: @ZathrusWriter I changed to $company_details['datas']..But still no luck..

Comment: @Patrick I set error_reporting(0). I guess thats not a problem here. But I tried It out and I am still having that same problem..

Comment: May be you are trying to load view with layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `home_view` view file should have only the minimal HTML markup needed for that company details so that the output will be loaded inside the `#cointainer` div.

If your view file has HTML codes for a full page, that full page HTML will be loaded inside that `#container` div, and you get repeated divs

Your view file should have just the below:

```
<div id="company">
<?php 
    foreach ($datas as $row) :
        echo $row['companyName']; 
    endforeach;
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes..!Thanks for your help.. Finally I got it.. The view page should contain only company div tag..